# Increase Jetty memory that is embedded in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am dealing with a large volume of data, and I get the following error :

```
java.lang.Exception: A mapping task failed: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I am starting jetty from a main method...like below:

```
final Server server = new Server(port);
server.start();
server.join();
```

I would expect that there might be some kind of configurations file..or some way to set -Xmx... but I can't find any..

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/18632192/775715

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I added -Xmx4096m at the VM options...and I get the same result...Thing is that  when I verify how much memory Jetty is using, is just about a tenth of that value...something like 400,000K... what am I missing?